# ASP.NET (Content is not supported outside the script or asp:content)

Tags: css, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I have created a nav bar on a nested master page that allows there to be a nav bar on each web form page that is created from it. I keep getting an error at the < html > tag on the top of the page as stated in the title. The code for the pages I have is as follow.

NestedMasterPage1.Master:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
 AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NestedMasterPage1.master.cs"
 Inherits="TGASAttempt.NestedMasterPage1" %>
     <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <link
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans"
 rel="stylesheet">

     <title>Navbar</title> </head> <body>
     <header>

         <div class="container">
             <img src="TGASlogo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

             <nav>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="~/">Home Page</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab3</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab4</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab5</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab6</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab7</a></li>
                     <li><a href="~/">Tab8</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </nav>

         </div>
     </header>
     <div>
             <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
             </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
         </div> </body> </html>
```

HomePage.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/NestedMasterPage1.master"
 CodeBehind="Home Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="TGASAttempt.WebForm1"  %>


 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
 runat="server">


      </asp:Content>
```

Site.Master

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="TGASAttempt.Site" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html> <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> </head> <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
             <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
             </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
         </div>
     </form> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the nested master page is nested within Site.Master there's no need to repeat all the html, head etc tags. The whole point of the main Master page is that it took care of all of that for you already. Also repeating it tries to declare a HTML document within another HTML document, which isn't a good thing.

Also the content in the nested page should be declared within an `<asp:Content>` block which corresponds to one of the `ContentPlaceHolder` blocks declared in Site.Master - this is what the error is telling you.

So for example:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
 AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NestedMasterPage1.master.cs"
 Inherits="TGASAttempt.NestedMasterPage1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <link
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans"
 rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Navbar</title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
 runat="server">

  <header>

     <div class="container">
         <img src="TGASlogo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

         <nav>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="~/">Home Page</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab4</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab5</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab6</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab7</a></li>
                 <li><a href="~/">Tab8</a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>

     </div>
  </header>
  <div>
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     </div>
</asp:Content>
```